# How to use curl cmd in c++/qt

Tags: c++, qt, curl, cmd

Why I'm getting in the `output` returned by `process` the following errors:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

The same code works fine when i press `win+r` and type

```
cmd.exe /k curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/jajabu33/test/branches"
```

```
QString Debugger::process(const QString& program, const QStringList& arguments)
{
    QProcess process;
    QByteArray output;
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]
    {
         output += process.readAllStandardOutput();
    });

    process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    process.start(program, arguments);

    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QObject::connect(&process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), &eventLoop, [&] { eventLoop.quit(); });
    eventLoop.exec();
    return output;
}


QString output = process("cmd.exe", {"/c curl -H \"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw\" -L \"https://github.com/jajabu33/test/branches\""});
```

Comment: I don't use Qt, but I see 6 arguments on the command line, and your code creates just one big argument.  Are you sure that will work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you mean split each "string" as one argument? `QString output = process("cmd.exe", {"/c", "curl", "-H", "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw", "-L", "https://github.com/jajabu33/test/branches"});` this also doesnt work, same error.

Comment: I would think you would need to break it up into 6 arguments.  Again, I don't use Qt, but that is the glaring difference between the command-line and your code.

Comment: Your `Accept` in the code is not the same as the one you used on the command line.  Note that the command on the command-line is quoted.  The one in your code has quotes, but those are quotes used to define the string, not actual quote characters used by the command processor.

Comment: `"\"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw\""` -- is what I would have expected in your code.

Comment: `QString output = process("cmd.exe",  {"/c", "curl", "-H", "\"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw\"", "-L", "\"https://github.com/jajabu33/test/branches\""});`  it continues causing bad format error: `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: So the `(6)` error is now gone?  If so, then again, I helped as much as I can since I don't use Qt.

Comment: Yes, the error now is (3) bad format, but i think it shouldn't be split for each arg

Comment: Why are you running this through `cmd`? Why not just run curl directly

Comment: Why not use `libcurl` rather than going via the command line program?

Comment: @AlanBirtles doesnt work either `QString output = process("curl.exe", {"-H", "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw", "-L", "https://github.com/jajabu33/test/branches"});`